# Does Parse or any other service provide feature to re-send notifications that are missed when device is offline?

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

If the device is offline for some period, APNS will only keep the last notification and re-send it when the device is back-online. My question is, if Parse or any other Push serivces provider has a feature to re-send the notifications that I missed during the offline period. If not, is there any way I can achieve this with current Parse features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure parse to send notifications when they became available https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

> When a user's device is turned off or not connected to the internet,
>   push notifications cannot be delivered. If you have a time sensitive
>   notification that is not worth delivering late, you can set an
>   expiration date.

Also check [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications)

Comment: I know that APNS will try to send again if the device wakes up again, but it only sends the latest one. But does the expiration feature in Parse helps re-send all notifications during the device offline (instead of only the last notification)? Thanks.

Comment: parse support whatever iOs has to offer. here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1 on QOS it says: Only one recent notification for a particular app is stored. If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as coalescing notifications.